# why moved code is not colored in git diff?

Tags: git, git-diff

I install latest git and configure it to highlight moved code:

```
$ git config diff.colormoved default
```

Here is how it looks when code is moved (see 1->2)
[image]

But 3-4 is not highlighted as moved code.

Here is standalone changes:

[image]

Comment: Ryan's answer is right (the un-altered color section is too short). It's also worth considering that `diff.colorMoved` is still experimental; it may change in a future Git.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See the documentation for `--color-moved`/`colormoved` in git-diff(1):

> `--color-moved[=<mode>]`
>
> Moved lines of code are colored differently. It can be changed by the `diff.colorMoved` configuration setting. The `<mode>` defaults to `no` if the option is not given and to `zebra` if the option with no mode is given. The mode must be one of:
>
> - **no**
>     Moved lines are not highlighted.
> - **default**
>        Is a synonym for zebra. This may change to a more sensible mode in the future.
> - **plain**
>        Any line that is added in one location and was removed in another location will be colored with color.diff.newMoved. Similarly
>     color.diff.oldMoved will be used for removed lines that are added
>     somewhere else in the diff. This mode picks up any moved line, but it
>     is not very useful in a review to
>        determine if a block of code was moved without permutation.
> - **zebra**
>        Blocks of moved text of at least 20 alphanumeric characters are detected greedily. The detected blocks are painted using either the
>     color.diff.{old,new}Moved color or
>     color.diff.{old,new}MovedAlternative. The change between the two
>     colors indicates that a new block was detected.
> - **dimmed_zebra**
>        Similar to zebra, but additional dimming of uninteresting parts of moved code is performed. The bordering lines of two adjacent blocks
>     are considered interesting, the rest is uninteresting.

specifically, that the default is `zebra` and that it detects

> Blocks of moved text of at least 20 alphanumeric characters

. `my $ctx =  shift;` doesn’t contain at least 20 alphanumeric characters. If you use `git diff --color-moved=plain`, or add `# ten more ANs` to the end of the line, your example will be highlighted as moved.

Comment: Is is possible to not to show moved lines at all?

Comment: @alper: Not as a built-in diff style, and I really wouldn’t recommend that since there could be false positives.

Answer (score 2):

Note there is another scenario where colored moved code (when the amount of code is enough) would have an improper side-effect:
"`git diff --color-moved --cc --stat -p`" did not work well due to funny interaction between a bug in color-moved and the rest.

This has been fixed in Git 2.21 (Feb. 2019)

See [commit dac03b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dac03b5518a053e52ed7ee20925970728d3ae4c3), [commit 04b19fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/04b19fcafd734245e61fd1c090cd7de8c2993eaa), [commit 8290faa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8290faa077784a2518d0a77b448ca2987c3baf07), [commit 8817f0c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8817f0cc6751199a996342fbc28bd343d231a5ca), [commit 48edf3a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48edf3a02addfa6385cd04c62a1c48671aad19aa), [commit 426fd36](https://github.com/git/git/commit/426fd36f4a899b5c2299fe2eed82affc7385c8cf) (24 Jan 2019) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5d2710b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d2710bd3c706c3375991972b630f9419551f24e), 05 Feb 2019)</sup>

> ### diff: clear emitted_symbols flag after use
>
> There's an odd bug when "`log --color-moved`" is used with the combination
>   of "`--cc --stat -p`": the stat for merge commits is erroneously shown
>   with the diff of the *next* commit.
>
> The included test demonstrates the issue.
>   Our history looks something like this:
>
> ```
> A-B-M--D
>    \ /
>     C
> ```
>
> When we run "`git log --cc --stat -p --color-moved`" starting at `D`, we get
>   this sequence of events:
>
> 1. The diff for `D` is using `-p`, so `diff_flush()` calls into
>       `diff_flush_patch_all_file_pairs()`. There we see that `o->color_moved`
>       is in effect, so we point `o->emitted_symbols` to a static local
>       struct, causing `diff_flush_patch()` to queue the symbols instead of
>       actually writing them out.
>       We then do our move detection, emit the symbols, and clear the
>       struct. But we leave `o->emitted_symbols` pointing to our struct.
> 2. Next we compute the diff for `M`. This is a merge, so we use the
>       combined diff code.
>       In `find_paths_generic()`, we compute the
>       pairwise diff between each commit and its parent. Normally this is
>       done with `DIFF_FORMAT_NO_OUTPUT`, since we're just looking for
>       intersecting paths. But since "`--stat --cc`" shows the first-parent
>       stat, and since we're computing that diff anyway, we enable
>       `DIFF_FORMAT_DIFFSTAT` for the first parent. This outputs the stat
>       information immediately, saving us from running a separate
>       first-parent diff later.
>       But where does that output go? Normally it goes directly to stdout,
>       but because `o->emitted_symbols` is set, we queue it. As a result, we
>       don't actually print the diffstat for the merge commit (yet), which
>       is wrong.
>
>    3. Next we compute the diff for `C`. We're actually showing a patch
>         again, so we end up in `diff_flush_patch_all_file_pairs()`, but this
>         time we have the queued stat from step 2 waiting in our struct.
>         We add new elements to it for `C`'s diff, and then flush the whole
>         thing. And we see the `diffstat` from `M` as part of `C`'s diff, which is
>         wrong.
>
> So triggering the bug really does require the combination of all of
>   those options.

Comment: Note to self: 11000 post in [git] tag

Comment: Is it possible to combine your solution with `--word-diff-regex='[^[:space:]]'`?

Comment: @alper The [`git diff` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) does not mention that those options are incompatible, so I suppose you can combine it with your option.

Comment: I have combine it but there are extra `[-` , `-]`, `{+`, `+}` characters are added

Comment: @alper OK, so there might be some post-processing to do with the output of the combined command.

Comment: Thanks ,  post-processing  covers trimming all the added characters right?

Comment: @alper That would be the idea, yes.