# why moved code is not colored in git diff when conflict occur?

Tags: git, git-diff

This question belongs to [other my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48165922/4632019)

But here I get merge conflict when doing cherry-pick:

```
On branch dev
You are currently cherry-picking commit 46b48c5b.
  (fix conflicts and run "git cherry-pick --continue")
  (use "git cherry-pick --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git cherry-pick --abort" to cancel the cherry-pick operation)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
1   both modified:   lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/OpenAPI3.pm
```

code is not colored as moved:

`$ git diff -b -w --ignore-blank-lines /home/kes/t/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/OpenAPI3.pm`
[image]

But when I mark conflict as resolved, then code is colored as moved:

[image]

Why it is not colored in first case?

```
$ git --version
git version 2.26.0
```

Comment: I would assume the difference is the coloring rules used for 3-way diff vs. for simple 2-way diff.  Couldn't really say beyond that, though