# How can I keep `--color-moved` theme while using `--word-diff=color` in git?

Tags: git, git-diff

`git diff --color-moved=dimmed_zebra --word-diff=color` shows moved block's colors as zebra theme.

---

But when I combine `--color-moved=dimmed_zebra` with `--word-diff=color` as: `git diff --color-moved --word-diff=color`

The moved block's color changed as: moved block from moved block as `red` and to move block as `green`.

Is it possible to keep the zebra theme for the moved block while using `--word-diff=color` flag?

Related: [why moved code is not colored in git diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48165922/2402577)

Comment: I don't believe it is - the "color-moved" code only works with the original line-oriented diffs, not with the word-diff. The word-diff code works "after the fact": basically Git runs the line diffs, then the word diff code sneaks in, grabs the line diff, and modifies it to pretend to be a word diff. This results in weird word diffs sometimes: the word-diff action may remove the difference, so that there's an empty hunk.

Comment: @tored Thanks for the well explaination.  Can hack to trick Git? or somehow force `word-diff code` to run after `word diff code`?

Comment: No. But Git is open source, so you can clone it and write your own word diff code and/or write your own color-moved code to use with the existing word-diff code.

Comment: I was thinking more basic solution where using `grep` to compare colored code blocks and if it detects same ones color them in different color

Comment: That constitutes writing new code. Note that grep alone won't do that: you'll need to break things up into parts that could be grepped, first. (You might want to read up on diff algorithms and the string-to-string edit/correction problem. There's a lot of literature here! To do a good job you want string-to-string edit with moves.)

Comment: Ah I always think about complex solutions than there is simpler ones. Let me investigate on Git's source code hoping calling `color-moved code` function called after `word-diff code` function might be the solution

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late to answer this question, but have you looked at DiffLens? (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DiffLens.difflens). If all you want to do is change the color of your diffs in the added and deleted sections, I believe DiffLens lets you do that. (You also get semantic diffs for TS, JS, JSON and CSS last I checked

Comment: does it work on terminal?